# sql rounding not always rounding up

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding, currency

I'm trying to do a round in sql but the result is very strange; here is what i do :

I'm using Mssql

I have a select :

```
Select num1, num2, num1 * num2, round(num1 * num2, 2)
from myTable
```

Datatype :

> num1 is a float
>
> num2 is a money

if the value of num1 is 15
and the value of num2 is 0.033
Here is my resultset :

> 15, 0.033, 0.495, 0.5

The problem is when I have those values :

if the value of num1 is 5
and the value of num2 is 0.045
Here is my resultset :

> 5, 0.045, 0.225, 0.22

Someone have an idea?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you should be using the MONEY datatype? There's a rather compelling writeup on why it should be avoided, if at all possible, in favor of decimal here: http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/throw-your-money-away/

Comment: I've tried this in my sqlect : round(convert(decimal(10, 3), num2) * num1, 2) and it's not working :(

Comment: Interesting... doing that works for me... try this: select round(CONVERT(decimal(10,3), 0.045) * 5, 2).   Just doing: "select round(5 * 0.045, 2)" also gives the proper result for me.

Comment: yeah this is working for me too, but when i'm converting my money value it's not working. So the problem is really with my money column, but why ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've converted my float column to money and it's seems to be working now.

Thanks all of you !

Comment: You should avoid money data type.  I would strongly recommend you consider the range of both values and use appropriate decimal instead and understand the rules of decimal scale and precision and make an appropriate decision as to what to do with fractional pennies.  In addition, as far as I know, it never makes sense to multiply two money types - you never have $x of $y - to get money, only to divide to get a scalar.  You would end up with x*y $^2 - there is no such thing as a square dollar, like there is a square foot or cubic meter or whatever.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at [this runnable example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61426/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-9266214-sql-rounding-not-always-rounding-up) in grid view mode (note also that text mode differs), you should see the problem:

```
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE (num1 float, num2 money);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (15, 0.033), (5, 0.045);

Select num1, num2, num1 * num2, round(num1 * num2, 2)
from @tbl;
```

Note that the number is actually .224999999, which rounds down to .22 - you need to be careful when looking at the non-binary output of SQL Server - it sometimes converts numbers to text in ways you are not expecting.

This comes from float * money operation resulting in a float which is subject to binary representation issues.

You should consider what it means for your float value and consider using decimal instead, and [look at the rules for scale and precision for decimal operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx).  Note that money is only somewhat similar to decimal(19, 4)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use long type instead of float. I think this is accuracy issue with floats.

Comment: Sorry i'm using mssql, i've edited my question, I don't think long exists in mssql

Comment: never use float if you want accurate math. Use a decimal type.

Answer (score 0):

What version of SQL are you using?

Try this code in Query Analyzer

```
DECLARE @num1 float
DECLARE @num2 money

SET @num1 = 15
SET @num2 = 0.033

SELECT
@Num1,
@Num2,
@Num1 * @Num2,
ROUND(@Num1 * @Num2,0),
ROUND(@Num1 * @Num2,1),
ROUND(@Num1 * @Num2,2),
ROUND(@Num1 * @Num2,3)
```

Float is an Approximation not a real number. Use Decimal instead.

```
DECLARE @num1 decimal
DECLARE @num2 money

SET @num1 = 5
SET @num2 = 0.045

SELECT
@Num1,
@Num2,
@Num1 * @Num2,
ROUND(@Num1 * @Num2,2),
ROUND(CAST(@Num1 as money) * @Num2,2)
```

Comment: Sorry i've forgot the ,2 in my round function , but this one is ok here is the result : 15 0.033 0.495 0 0.5 0.5 0.495 ; It's my other data, the 5 and 0.045 that give me trouble